# How to get a list of strings or type T from simplejdbctemplate query?

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I would like to get ALL rows from my simplejdbctemplate query tables and would like to add them to a list. What would be the best way to do that?
I've tried this:

```
List<String> carbrands = (List<String>) jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select brand from cars", String.class);
```

So I'd expect a list of strings like:

```
toyota
hyundai
bmw
benz
...
```

But I can't get this to work. And if I try to do this for multiple types, I get stuck:

```
List<Car> values = (List<Car>) jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select name,brand,value from cars", Car.class);
```

This doesn't work either. I'd like it to return Cars, which I defined as name, brand, value. But... I've googled around and can't find a solution. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) query 1 is correct and should work.

2) query 2 should be

```
List<Car> list = jdbcTemplate.query("select name,brand,value from cars", new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Car>(Car.class));
```

Car should be a valid JavaBean - must have a public no-arg constructor and public setters / getters

```
public class Car {
     String name;

     public void setName(String name) {
           this.name = name;
     }

     public String getName() {
           return name;
     }
     ...
}
```

alternatevely you can read cars as maps of columns

```
List<Map<String, Object>> cars = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select * from cars");
for(Map car : cars) {
     String brand = (String)car.get("brand");
     String name = (String)car.getName("name");
     ....
}
```

Comment: Urgh... I have arguments for the name, brand, value in my car class. If I took that out now that would screw up way too much stuff at this point so I'd rather not if I could avoid it. Is there any other way around it? Also, my maven says I have inconvertible types for query 1.

Comment: List<Map<String, Object>> cars = t.queryForList("select name, ..."); will give you a list of maps, 1 map (columnName/value) is 1 car

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean -- t.queryList? Did you just use t as an abbreviation for jdbcTemplate? Also, I do not see any queryforlist with just the query as the arg... what should I put in after the query? Thanks! (Sorry, I've never been really been able to understand simplejdbctemplate)

Comment: t is JdbcTemplate; t.query("select name,brand,value from cars") will return all cars.

Comment: Ok... but which query was that in reference to? 1 or 2? Sorry if it's obvious :(

Comment: this is instead of #2 - since you cannot get a list of Cars then get a list of maps with jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select * from cars")

Comment: I'm not sure how that would help -- I could make an iterator of <map,object> but since I don't know which one will be in there (and also I do not know ahead of the time values in the tables) there will be no way of extracting the values from the map...